# Drupal 7 - Ubercart - Attributes in Views Fields

Tags: attributes, drupal-7, view, drupal-modules, ubercart

I have products that have attributes for 'color' & 'strength'. I'm trying to get those options listed under those attributes as fields for views, so that I can use them as filters. So for example sort by color & strength.

I've looked all around on google and can only find modules for Drupal 6. Anyone know of anything for 7?

Answer (score 1):

Like said in the previous post I had 2 attributes 'color' & 'strength' which I needed to match for exact product matches but ubercart didn't have anything for that, so I wrote them into URL for get statements as variables 1 & 2, so for example a URL which had both attributes selected would look like:

`www.website.com/node/68?1=96&2=7`

Sometimes one variable would be set but not the other, so I had to make up for that also by using a % wildcard. Here's the code for that part

```
//  Since PHP's serialize function sometimes serializes in the incorrect order,
//  here we manually build the comparison key
//  Additionally append the image links urls with provided strength/color data

if( isset( $_REQUEST['1'] ) ) {
    $_1 = $_REQUEST['1'];
    if( $_1 !== '%' ) $url[] = "1=$_1";
} else $_1 = '%';

if( isset( $_REQUEST['2'] ) ) {
    $_2 = $_REQUEST['2'];
    if( $_2 !== '%' ) $url[] = "2=$_2";
} else $_2 = '%';

$combination = "a:2:{i:1;s:";
$combination .= $_1 == '%' ? '%:"%";' : strlen($_1) . ':"' . $_1 . '";';
$combination .= "i:2;s:";
$combination .= $_2 == '%' ? '%:"%";' : strlen($_2) . ':"' . $_2 . '";';
$combination .= '}';

// if some products don't have a second attribute at all
$combination2 = "a:1:{i:1;s:";
$combination2 .= $_1 == '%' ? '%:"%"' : strlen($_1) . ':"' . $_1 . '";';
$combination2 .= ';}';
```

Underneath that I had to do some extra queries like if a taxonomy was set and check if some dynamic properties were set, thats why the `WHERE` is stored in a variable. Frankly they'll just confuse anyone so I left them out. But for your sake the next part you just need to query it.

```
$where = "WHERE (pa.combination LIKE :pattern1 OR pa.combination LIKE :pattern2) AND s.stock IS NOT NULL";
$comparison = array( ':pattern1' => $combination,
                     ':pattern2' => $combination2 );

$filtered = db_query(
    "
        SELECT pa.nid, pa.model, pa.combination, n.title, p.sell_price, f.uri
        FROM {uc_product_adjustments} pa
        LEFT JOIN {node} n ON pa.nid = n.nid
        LEFT JOIN {uc_products} p ON pa.nid = p.nid
        LEFT JOIN {field_data_uc_product_image} i ON i.entity_type = 'node' AND i.entity_id = n.nid
        LEFT JOIN {file_managed} f ON f.fid = i.uc_product_image_fid
        LEFT JOIN {uc_product_stock} s ON pa.model = s.sku AND s.stock <> '0'
        $where
    ",
    $comparison
);
```

Lastly loop over the results and store them in a normal array

```
foreach( $filtered as $i => $record ) {
    if( is_int( array_search( $record->nid, $nids ) ) ) continue;
    else {
        $nids[] = $record->nid;
        $result[] = $record;
    }
}
```

This code checks for any products that match any of the attribute values that are currently in stock

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at these sandbox projects : [UC Views Attributes Work](http://drupal.org/sandbox/NigelCunningham/1271796) and [UC attribute views](http://drupal.org/sandbox/hachreak/1693408).

I'm looking for a similar feature, as it seems not possible to get UC attributes into a view. I cannot test myself right now as I have a deadline this weekend for a project, but I'd be happy to have your feedback.

Comment: I ended up writing the SQL queries myself. Just holler if you'd like to see the code for it.

Comment: I'm hollering as well!